# Why do these errors come up?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, installation

I deleted eclipse then i downloaded and installed it again. but now nothing works:

- whenever I press something, this error would pop up :

```
(Errors occurred during the build. Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'test'. java.lang.NullPointerException)
```

whenever I try to run some code, i get this error :

```
(Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.lang.module.FindException: Module test not found)
```

- i get this warning too :

```
(Description Resource Path Location Type Build path specifies execution environment JavaSE-11. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment. test Build path JRE System Library Problem)
```

I'm 13 years old and i'm new to java, eclipse and software setup in general, Would appreciate any help. ;)

Comment: Install a newer version of eclipse, or an older version of Java.

Comment: No still does not work

Comment: Then you still have an older version of eclipse, it does not support such a new version of Java. The message "There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment." is pretty cut and dry.

Comment: How did you 'delete' Eclipse?  Formal uninstall procedure?  It looks as if there might be remnants of the older installation around.

Comment: You have a project in your workspace that uses JDK11 but you upgraded and now the project is broken. To fix this the first step is to determine what versions of Eclipse and Java you are using now?  To find these from within Eclipse select (a) Help -> About Eclipse IDE, and (b) Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs) Let us know this information then we can help you get it straightened out.  Ideally you should probably be using Eclipse IDE for Java Developers version 2019-03 (4.11.0) and Java JDK 11.0.3.

Comment: Yes, I am using those versions of Java (build 1.8.0_211-b12) and Eclipse (Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0) but the JDK versions is (JDK 12).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, Thank you I solved it.
You download JDK 11.0.3 then...
You just go to Preferences > Java > Installed Java > Add > Standard VM > put Java 11.0.3 in JRE Home > JRE Name just type anything you want > then press Finish and tick Home or the new one you named and made.
BTW the Java 11.0.3 is in Library >> Java > JavaVirtualMachines >> Java (Version) >> contents >> home
Make sure to open the file at the contents no at jdk-(version).jdk